# Помогите разобраться с порядком вызова функции в html из javascript

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Требуется вызвать функцию `init()` на `onClick` кнопки. А в свою очередь функция вызывается сразу при загрузке страницы! Каким образом вызвать определенную функцию из файла *.js если их там несколько? И почему функция выполняется произвольно сразу при загрузке страницы?

ws.js

```js
var wsUri = "wss://echo.websocket.org/";
var output;
  function init()
  {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    alert('gjxtve');
    testWebSocket();
  }


function testWebSocket()
{
  websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
  websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
  websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
  websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
  websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
}

function onOpen(evt)
{
  writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
  alert('connected');
  doSend("WebSocket rocks");
}

function onClose(evt)
{
  writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
    alert('DISCONNECTED');
}

function onMessage(evt)
{
  writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
  alert(evt.data);
  websocket.close();
}

function onError(evt)
{
  writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  alert(evt.data);
}

function doSend(message)
{
  writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
  websocket.send(message);
}

function writeToScreen(message)
{
  var pre = document.createElement("p");
  pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
  pre.innerHTML = message;
  output.appendChild(pre);
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>WebSocket Test</title>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="ws.js">  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
  <input text="connect" type="button" onclick="init()">
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Почему произвольно? Вы ведь сами об этом попросили: `window.addEventListener("load", init, false)`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> И почему функция выполняется произвольно сразу при загрузке страницы?

```
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

Данная строка добавляет обработчик события *load*. Когда происходит это событие вызывается функция *init*.

Если уберете эту строчку - то функция будет вызывается только по кнопке.

Comment: Спасибо извиняюсь за невнимательность.